# RDP to KVM Guest

Tags: virtualization, remote-desktop, kvm-virtualization

KVM Guest is a Windows machine. I set the hooks to forward port 3389 to the guest. But RDP cannot connect. RDP is enabled in Guest. Does someone have an idea?

```
Guest="win"
Guest_ip="192.168.1.3"

if [[ $1 = $Guest ]]
then
        if [[ $2 = "stopped" || $2 = "reconnect" ]]
        then
                iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to $Guest_ip:3389
                iptables -D FORWARD -d $Guest_ip -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp \
                --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
        fi
        if [[ $2 = "start" || $2 = "reconnect" ]]
        then
                iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to $Guest_ip:3389
                iptables -I FORWARD -d $Guest_ip -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp \
                --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
        fi
fi
```

> Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
>   default         10.1.226.206    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
>   10.1.226.206    *               255.255.255.254 U     0      0        0 eth0
>   10.1.226.207    *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
>   192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hooks:

```
redir --lport 3389 --caddr=GuestIP --cport 3389
```

Answer (score 0):

- See if your script is fine by adding "set -x" in the head to get some
  debug.
- Try to scan the destination port with nmap.
- Have a look at the traffic with tcpdump.

b.t.w. Is "nat -A" correct?

If you are connecting to a Guest from outside the Host you need a route to the Guest.